# how to make a loop update sub program based on program id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a program to calculate the percentage of contract value based on the program id, where the program has several sub program.

for the example:

```
+------------+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
| Id program | Id sub | contract value | sub value  | Percentage |
+------------+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
|          1 |    111 |    100.000.000 | 10.000.000 | 10%        |
|          2 |    112 |    100.000.000 | 20.000.000 | 20%        |
+------------+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
```

if I change the contract value from 100,000,000 to 50,000,000 in setting, 
the result will be like

```
+------------+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
| Id program | Id sub | contract value | sub value  | Percentage |
+------------+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
|          1 |    111 |    50.000.000  | 10.000.000 | 20%        |
|          2 |    112 |    50.000.000  | 20.000.000 | 40%        |
+------------+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
```

if the value of the contract is changed then the sub value does not change tp percentage according to the value of the contract that has been changed, the formula is the value of sub / contract value * 100

my controller

```
public function add($id) { 

  $data['realisasi'] = $this->realisasi_model->all_realisasi_program($id);
  $data = array (
    'id_program' => $id,
    'contract_value' => $contract_value
  );
  $this->addendum_model->update_contract($id, $data);

  if ($this->addendum_model->update_contract($data)) {
    $percent_update = 50000000 / $contract_value* 100; 

    $datareal = array(
       'REAL_SUBPRO_PERCENT' => $percent_update
    );

    $this->realisasi_model->update_percent($id, $datareal);
  }
}
```

my model

```
public function update_percent($id, $datareal) {
    return $this->db->update('TX_REAL_SUB_PROGRAM', $datareal, 
    array('id_program' => $id));
}
```

i want to change 50000000 with sub value from realisasi_model, but i dont know. 
should I use foreach inside the controller? 
I really appreciate if you can help me thank you

Comment: "i want to change 50000000 with sub value from realisasi_model" ... for all rows? can you explain a bit better? where are you getting `$contract_value`?

Comment: also your formula doesn't match the one in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

You will have to check a few things such as column names and the formula because I saw quite a few discrepancies between your code and what you were explaining.

Controller:

```
public function update_contract_value() {
    $contract_val_new = $this->input->post('contract_value');
    if (is_null($contract_val_new)) {
        show_error('Missing parameters.');
    }
    if ($this->somemodel->change_contract_value_all($contract_val_new)) {
        echo 'Done';
    } else {
        show_error('Query failed.');
    }
}
```

Model functions:

```
public function change_contract_value_all($new_contract_value) {
        $rows = $this->get_all();
        if (!$rows) {
            return false; // no items in table
        }
        $this->db->trans_start();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $data = array(
                'contract_value' => $new_contract_value, // check column name?
                'REAL_SUBPRO_PERCENT' => $this->calc_contract_percent($new_contract_value, $row->REAL_SUBPRO_PERCENT) // check column name `REAL_SUBPRO_PERCENT`?
            );
            $this->db->update('TX_REAL_SUB_PROGRAM', $data, array('id_program' => $row->id_program);
        }
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        return $this->db->trans_status();
    }

    public function calc_contract_percent($sub_value, $contract_value) {
        return ($sub_value / $contract_value) * 100;
    }

    public function get_all() {
        $q = $this->db->get('TX_REAL_SUB_PROGRAM');
        if ($q->num_rows() < 1) {
            return false;
        }
        return $q->result();
    }
```